# Добавить кнопку в конец UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Добрый день!

Задача следующая:

Добавить кнопку "Загрузить еще" в конец UITableView.

Загрузка данный в таблицу осуществляется через сервис Parse и в данный момент количество "постов" ограничивается значением NSInteger.

Хочу в конец таблицы добавить кнопку, которая будет изменять значение NSInteger и догружать посты в таблицу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким способом я могу это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить кнопку можно следующим образом:

```
UIButton *buttonAtTheBottomOfTable = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 50.)];
[buttonAtTheBottomOfTable setTitle:@"load more shit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = buttonAtTheBottomOfTable;
```

Но есть гораздо более интересный способ по подгрузке следующих страниц. 
Делаем в контроллере проперти:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lastScrollViewOffsetY;
```

дефайн:

```
#define LOAD_NEXT_PAGE_OFFSET 600.
```

и методы:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y+scrollView.frame.size.height) > (scrollView.contentSize.height-LOAD_NEXT_PAGE_OFFSET) &&
    (self.lastScrollViewOffsetY+scrollView.frame.size.height) <= (scrollView.contentSize.height-LOAD_NEXT_PAGE_OFFSET)) {
        [self loadNextPage];
    }

    // and finally remember the current offset as the last
    self.lastScrollViewOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}


- (void)loadNextPage {
    // тут обрабатываем тот факт что таблица прошла некий порог скролла и находится 
    // почти внизу и пора бы уже следующую страницу грузить
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решение то, что нужно!
Осталось придумать как догрузить посты)

Comment: Все получилось)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал использовать эту библиотеку для удобства (сам ей пользуюсь): 
https://github.com/OpenFibers/DragRefreshAndLoadMoreTableDemo

Возможность добавить обновить и загрузить больше в UITableView. 
Легко кастомизируется.

Точно работает на iOS 7 и iOS 8

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно попробую